# Show that $\left| \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{z} \right| \le \left|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y} \right| + \left|\frac{1}{y} - \frac{1}{z} \right|$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, metric-spaces

I'm trying to prove that

$$ \left| \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y} \right| $$

is a metric on $X = \mathbb R^+$.

The properties of non-negativity and symmetry are obvious (do I actually even need to prove them?), but the tricky one is, as usual the inequality property, i.e.

$$ d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(y,z) \text{ for any } z \in X. $$

So, ok, I have that

$$ d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(y,z) \\
\iff \left| \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{z} \right| \le \left|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y} \right| + \left|\frac{1}{y} - \frac{1}{z} \right| \\
\iff \left| \frac{1}{x} \right|- \left| \frac{1}{z} \right| \le \left| \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{z} \right| \le \left|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y} \right| + \left|\frac{1}{y} - \frac{1}{z} \right| $$

...and that's about as far as I've gotten–which is to say, not very far. I also tried multiplying both sides by $ \left| \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{z} \right| $, but that wasn't very fruitful. If someone could point me in the right direction, it'd be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $\delta(x,y):=|x-y|$ is a metric in $\mathbb R$ (and hence $\delta(1/x,1/z)\leqslant\delta(1/x,1/y)+\delta(1/y,1/z)\;\;\forall x,y,z>0$)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is just $$ \left| \frac {1}{x}-\frac{1}{z} \right|=\left|\frac {1}{x}-\frac {1}{y}+\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{z}\right| \leq \left|\frac {1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}\right|+\left|\frac {1}{y}-\frac{1}{z}\right|$$ using the Module properties

Comment: This is also called the [Triangle Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).