# Proof that $d(x,y) = |\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}|$ defines a Metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am trying to prove that $d(x,y) = |\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}|$ is a Metric.

I already managed to prove:

1. $d(x,y)\geq 0$
2. $d(x,y)\geq 0$ iff $x=y$
3. $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$

But I am stuc at the 4th property:

4. $d(x,y) \leq d(x,z) + d(z,y)$ (The triangle inequality)

Thus far I came to:

$|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{z}| + |\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{y}| = |\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{x}| + |\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{y}|$

But now I am stuk. I understand that this is probably a basic question but I am new to the world of Real Analysis.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a minus sign instead of a plus sign?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo.

Comment: The triangle inequality is actually  $d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1461723/show-that-left-frac1x-frac1z-right-le-left-frac1x-frac

Comment: A metric, in which space? That is a crucial missing point. You know, $1/x$ doesn't make sense for all inputs $x$ :-)

Answer (score 4):

$$d(x,y) = \left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}\right| = \left|\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{z}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{y}\right)\right|\\\leq \left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{z}\right|+\left|\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{y}\right|=d(x,z)+d(z,y)$$

Answer (score 0):

It is essential to say that you are working on $\mathbb{R}^{*}:=(-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty)$.

It is a general fact that for any **bijective** function $f$, defining $d$ by:

$$d(x,y):=|f(x)-f(y)|$$

will give a distance (= a metric). It is called a "distance transfer". See among many examples [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1682225p10727585).

Here $f:x \mapsto 1/x$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{R}^{*}$ onto itself.

Comment: No comment about this general answer ?